# Why can't I flag as "not an answer" even though I've never raised this flag?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, flags

This is either a bug or an unknown feature I'm unaware of but when I try to flag an answer, the "not an answer" option is grayed out and a message saying "you have already raised this type of flag", even though I never did for that answer. See the following image:

[image: What I'm seeing when trying to flag]

Is there something I'm missing? Is it possible I can't flag it as "not an answer" because someone else already did?

Comment: What specific answer/question are you talking about?

Comment: This answer: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/204181/4027

Comment: Can confirm: same happens to me. I cannot flag as not an answer. I haven't done anything on the site yet today, and that answer is ~1 hour old.

Comment: I *can* flag the answer above as not an answer though (or at least the options looks like it's available, didn't actually try).

Comment: could be a bug, maybe if someone already flagged it as "not an answer" it acts as if you did.

Comment: Yea, going to assume something like that, because that specific answer was in the low quality review queue for me just now.

Answer (score 6):

This was in fact a regression.  It will be fixed very soon.  Details are here:  [Flag dialog tells me I've flagged a post I've never seen before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248080/flag-dialog-tells-me-ive-flagged-a-post-ive-never-seen-before)

Answer (score -1):

Because you reviewed the post in the review queue and [recommended deletion](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/118242).

Although it's not clear, this counts sorta like a NAA flag, and hence excludes you from flagging the post further.

Comment: @JohnoBoy You must have done though, [you are listed as a reviewer of the post here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/118242).

Comment: Edit: Deleted my incorrect comment. But I recommended deletion only after I couldn't flag it.

Comment: @JohnoBoy You're right. I'll investigate further.

Comment: See also my comments, I could not flag it, then after that went through the queue and cast a delete vote that way.

Comment: @Arperum This could be a bug. I'll report back if I hear anything.

Comment: @fredley [Another answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/204194/39891) that I didn't interact with in any way, still can't cast NAA vote. It's also in the first post review queue, and can't flag through there either.